# Empty Timeline despite adding ConcatenatingMediaSouce in ExoPlayer

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer

I am having a bunch of songs of which I am making a `ConcatenatingMediaSource`

```
...

allSongs.forEach {
            concatenatingMediaSource.addMediaSource(makeMediaSource(it.source))
        }
player!!.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource)

Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: period count ==> ${player!!.currentTimeline.periodCount} \n " +
                "window count ==> ${player!!.currentTimeline.windowCount}")

...
```

*MakeMediaSource function*

```
private fun makeMediaSource(sourceOfSong: String): ProgressiveMediaSource {

        val dataSourceFactory = DefaultDataSourceFactory(
            this,
            getUserAgent(this, "ApplicationName")
        )

        return ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
            .createMediaSource(
                Uri.parse(sourceOfSong)
            )
    }
```

I wanted to play a random song from the playlist so when I used `seekTo(windowIndex, playbackPosition)` the app crashed. Then upon checking the `windowCount` and `periodCount` of the timeline after adding the `ConcatenatingMediaSource` to the player I got *0* for both of them and the *timeline* is empty as well but I should be having the *window* and *period* count as many as the size of *ConcatenatingMediaSource*, according to the official [sources](https://exoplayer.dev/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/Timeline.html). I don't understand why is it happening?

Comment: are you adding/attaching mediasource to exoplayer?

Comment: Yes, the playlist is getting played.

Comment: Please add some more code where you used the seekTo(windowIndex, playbackPosition) and add the crash log

Comment: The crash log would say that the windowIndex is invalid as the timeline remains empty after I add the ConcatenatingMediaSource to the player. Please see the latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out, I was preparing the player with the `ConcatenatingMediaSource` and just after that I was logging the `windowCount` and `periodCount` of the *Timeline*

```
player!!.prepare(concatenatingMediaSource)
Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: period count ==> ${player!!.currentTimeline.periodCount} \n " +
                "window count ==> ${player!!.currentTimeline.windowCount}")
```

I figured out that the `prepare` method works *asynchronously* and it takes some time to get the player ready otherwise why would they have provided the *listener* for. So, I did a log of *windowCount* inside `onPlayerStateChanged` and it works.